# Import Object Format with applied Paragraph Styles

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am importing styles from a separate **.indd** and applying them with the function `newTextFrame.appliedObjectStyle` The Object Style has the "Apply next Paragraph Style" Option enabled, but when i execute my script, only the first paragraph style is applied. When i reapply the object style after my script has finished, it is working.

[image: Object Style Preferences]

[image]

I tried adding `.applyNextParagraphStyle`or `.enableParagraphStyle` but it didn't work ( I know these are ususally used for creating object styles)

Comment: It hard to tell what's going on inside this particular script with no its code in front my eyes. If you just want to apply some paragraph style over all paragraphs inside the text frame it can be done pretty easy. Something like this I suppose: `newTextFrame.parentStory.texts.everyItem().applyParagraphStyle(myPgfStyle, true);`

Comment: I had exactly this working before, but I need multiple paragraph styles combined with character styles in different configurations, so i decided to do it with object styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.

It had something to do with the order of my code. Basically i was applying the object style before loading the content. Now, that the content is already placed in the text frame and THEN applied with the object style, it works fine!